# Jquery inside VS cordova app: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, cordova, content-security-policy

Recently, I found out about Cordova and also started a test project to see how this works. The problem is that when I included Jquery it shows me an error:

> **$ is not defined**

The html code looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--
        Customize the content security policy in the meta tag below as needed. Add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src to enable inline JavaScript.
        For details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521
    -->
    <!--My note:I added unsafe-inline-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>-->

    <title>SchoolMusic</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:coral ">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log($(document));
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Initially I used the local version of Jquery(saved in "scripts/jquery.js" file-the minified version). It didn't worked. Then I tried the code with the "remote-online" jquery code from "code.jquery.com". The same error.

Later ,I thought the security policy might cause some problems (although I couldn't see why because the other local scripts loaded corectly:cordova.js and index.js) and ...it worked! I still want to keep the policy. The question is: why is not my file loaded when the policy is used? And: how do I allow,in the policy,other files to be loaded from internet(for example,from code.jquery.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed. I replaced,by mistake.the 'self' argument from "default-src" with 'unsafe-inline'. So,actually,no script was loaded(not even the index.js or cordova.js). 
This is how the final code looks like:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--
        Customize the content security policy in the meta tag below as needed. Add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src to enable inline JavaScript.
        For details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521
    -->
    <!--My note:I added unsafe-inline-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>-->

    <title>SchoolMusic</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:coral ">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log($(document));
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```